# Angular 4 does't update *ngfor list on IE?

Tags: angular

I have a simple list like:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newItem" (click)="addNewItem()">

<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of list">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

The list gets refetched after a new item is entered but the list doesn't get updated on IE11.

On Chore it works perfectly!

es6-shim is included!

Even if I refresh the page it doesn't update. It updates only if re build fear app.

On the console I see no errors but well the updated data from the server.

UPDATE: It was caching issue on IE. **It is solved** with adding cache control to headers:

```
this.headers = new Headers({
    'Cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache'
})
```

Any tips?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: IE and Edge are not the same navigator. Which one are you talking about ? both ?

Comment: Do you see any error in the console of IE ?

Comment: are you adding the object inside addNewItem?

Comment: IE actually.. updated my question

Comment: Have you included the polyfills? https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

Comment: Show code for `addNewItem()` and enough so we understand how the `list` is fetched and updated

Comment: @Z.Bagley just using angular cli with pollyfills.ts...I ll check it double

Comment: do you have a reference to es6-shim ?

Comment: @Brice no errors..

Comment: @Vega not yet..;/ still searching.

Comment: @Mar thanks for the updated solution re IE caching. I was experiencing the same issue and adding the mentioned headers in my service request solved it for me too.